# Using Bouncy Castle to extract certificate information from android

Tags: java, android, bouncycastle

I am trying to use bouncy castle to read the content of CERT.RSA in an Android apk file.

By using : `openssl pkcs7 -inform DER -in CERT.RSA -noout -print_certs -text`

I am get the following, which seems correct :

```
Certificate:
Data:
    Version: 3 (0x2)
    Serial Number:
        93:6e:ac:be:07:f2:01:df
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: C=US, ST=California, L=Mountain View, O=Android, OU=Android, CN=Android/emailAddress=android@android.com
    Validity
        Not Before: Feb 29 01:33:46 2008 GMT
        Not After : Jul 17 01:33:46 2035 GMT
    Subject: C=US, ST=California, L=Mountain View, O=Android, OU=Android, CN=Android/emailAddress=android@android.com
    Subject Public Key Info:
        Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            Public-Key: (2048 bit)
            Modulus:
                00:d6:93:19:04:de:c6:0b:24:b1:ed:c7:62:e0:d9:
                d8:25:3e:3e:cd:6c:eb:1d:e2:ff:06:8c:a8:e8:bc:
                a8:cd:6b:d3:78:6e:a7:0a:a7:6c:e6:0e:bb:0f:99:
                35:59:ff:d9:3e:77:a9:43:e7:e8:3d:4b:64:b8:e4:
                fe:a2:d3:e6:56:f1:e2:67:a8:1b:bf:b2:30:b5:78:
                c2:04:43:be:4c:72:18:b8:46:f5:21:15:86:f0:38:
                a1:4e:89:c2:be:38:7f:8e:be:cf:8f:ca:c3:da:1e:
                e3:30:c9:ea:93:d0:a7:c3:dc:4a:f3:50:22:0d:50:
                08:07:32:e0:80:97:17:ee:6a:05:33:59:e6:a6:94:
                ec:2c:b3:f2:84:a0:a4:66:c8:7a:94:d8:3b:31:09:
                3a:67:37:2e:2f:64:12:c0:6e:6d:42:f1:58:18:df:
                fe:03:81:cc:0c:d4:44:da:6c:dd:c3:b8:24:58:19:
                48:01:b3:25:64:13:4f:bf:de:98:c9:28:77:48:db:
                f5:67:6a:54:0d:81:54:c8:bb:ca:07:b9:e2:47:55:
                33:11:c4:6b:9a:f7:6f:de:ec:cc:8e:69:e7:c8:a2:
                d0:8e:78:26:20:94:3f:99:72:7d:3c:04:fe:72:99:
                1d:99:df:9b:ae:38:a0:b2:17:7f:a3:1d:5b:6a:fe:
                e9:1f
            Exponent: 3 (0x3)
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
            48:59:00:56:3D:27:2C:46:AE:11:86:05:A4:74:19:AC:09:CA:8C:11
        X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
            keyid:48:59:00:56:3D:27:2C:46:AE:11:86:05:A4:74:19:AC:09:CA:8C:11
            DirName:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Android/OU=Android/CN=Android/emailAddress=android@android.com
            serial:93:6E:AC:BE:07:F2:01:DF

        X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
            CA:TRUE
Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
    7a:af:96:8c:eb:50:c4:41:05:51:18:d0:da:ab:af:01:5b:8a:
    76:5a:27:a7:15:a2:c2:b4:4f:22:14:15:ff:da:ce:03:09:5a:
    bf:a4:2d:f7:07:08:72:6c:20:69:e5:c3:6e:dd:ae:04:00:be:
    29:45:2c:08:4b:c2:7e:b6:a1:7e:ac:9d:be:18:2c:20:4e:b1:
    53:11:f4:55:d8:24:b6:56:db:e4:dc:22:40:91:2d:75:86:fe:
    88:95:1d:01:a8:fe:b5:ae:5a:42:60:53:5d:f8:34:31:05:24:
    22:46:8c:36:e2:2c:2a:5e:f9:94:d6:1d:d7:30:6a:e4:c9:f6:
    95:1b:a3:c1:2f:1d:19:14:dd:c6:1f:1a:62:da:2d:f8:27:f6:
    03:fe:a5:60:3b:2c:54:0d:bd:7c:01:9c:36:ba:b2:9a:42:71:
    c1:17:df:52:3c:db:c5:f3:81:7a:49:e0:ef:a6:0c:bd:7f:74:
    17:7e:7a:4f:19:3d:43:f4:22:07:72:66:6e:4c:4d:83:e1:bd:
    5a:86:08:7c:f3:4f:2d:ec:21:e2:45:ca:6c:2b:b0:16:e6:83:
    63:80:50:d2:c4:30:ee:a7:c2:6a:1c:49:d3:76:0a:58:ab:7f:
    1a:82:cc:93:8b:48:31:38:43:24:bd:04:01:fa:12:16:3a:50:
    57:0e:68:4d
```

But I don't get the public key modulus and the other necessary stuff when I'm using Bouncy Castle. The pubkey is just null. I guess I made some mistake in the code, but it is weird that I get everything I want, except for the public key.

```
X509CertParser certParser = new X509CertParser();
FileInputStream stream;
X509CertificateObject cert= null;
try {
stream = new FileInputStream("CERT.RSA");
    certParser.engineInit(stream);
    cert =  (X509CertificateObject) certParser.engineRead();
    stream.close();

    if(cert.getPublicKey()==null)System.out.println("NULL");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This code prints NULL, while the openssl call tells me the modulus etc.

What should I do to get the pubkey in Java ? (maybe it is possible to use android sdk or something else to get the data instead of bouncy castle)

Edit:

I forgot to mention that i already tried David Grants code, which gives me the error message, that the DerInputStream is too big:

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: Unable to initialize, java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=127, too big.
at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:199)
at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:107)
at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:322)
```

Comment: Have you tried my solution? While it might not be the best long term choice, it may help prove that your input file is valid. If you receive an exception with that too, then perhaps the file is to blame.

Comment: I got this error also

Answer (score 13):

You don't need BC for reading a certificate from a DER stream, you can do it just fine in Java SE:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("CERT.RSA");
CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) factory.generateCertificate(in);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but i already tried that code (i totally forgot to mention that one) and i returns an error, i edited the original post and added the information.

Comment: What does the CERT.RSA file actually contain?

Answer (score 2):

If you are set on using BouncyCastle, you could instead try using the [`PEMReader`](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/openssl/PEMReader.html) class. (Clearly your certificate would then need to be in PEM format, not DER).

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("/path/to/cert.pem");
PEMReader pemReader = new PEMReader(fileReader);
Object obj = pemReader.readObject();
pemReader.close(); // sloppy IO handling, be thorough in production code
X509CertificateObject certObj = (X509CertificateObject) obj;
System.out.println(certObj.getPublicKey());
```

For some reason, the code you posted just won't suck out the public key. I have no idea why.

Comment: it dows not work for me, because the certObj is null at the end, but everthing runs fine without any failure...

Comment: With BC 1.7, `PEMReader.readObject()` issues `X509CertificateHolder` which is not a `X509CertificateObject`. The only way I could find to suck out the `X509Certificate` from a holder was to use the `getEncoded()` method to get the raw unPEMified DER format and then use David Grant's answer to read that.

Answer (score 2):

The APK is simply a jar file. Use the [JarFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/jar/JarFile.html) to parse it and then list the [JarEntry](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/jar/JarEntry.html)'s, calling the `getCertifiates()` method to get signing certificates. There is usually only one. You can cast to `X509Certifiate` to get all certificate info. Note that you don't have to extract the CERT.RSA file, just pass the APK file to the `JarFile` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the `CERT.RSA` Files by using the `PKCS7` Method:

```
PKCS7 p7 = new PKCS7(new FileInputStream("CERT.RSA"));
p7.getCertificates();
```

this will return you a Array of `X509Certificate`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SpongyCastle to get correctly. I made some code below, you can actually get the things like openssl does.
SpongyCastle Jars can be downloaded from below:-
[core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.madgag.spongycastle/core/1.58.0.0), [prov](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.madgag.spongycastle/prov/1.58.0.0), [pkix](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.madgag.spongycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.58.0.0)

```
/*
 * This program is used for parsing META-INF/CERT.[RSA|DSA|EC] file and converting it to x509.pem.
 * Ref :- net.sourceforge.dkartaschew.halimede.data.PKCS7Decoder.java
 *
 * Created : 5th February 2020
 * Author  : HemanthJabalpuri
 *
 * This file has been put into the public domain.
 * You can do whatever you want with this file.
 */

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

// need core.jar, prov.jar, bcpkix-jdk15on.jar of spongycastle
import org.spongycastle.cert.X509CertificateHolder;
import org.spongycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509CertificateConverter;
import org.spongycastle.cms.CMSSignedData;
import org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.spongycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMWriter;
import org.spongycastle.util.encoders.Base64;

public class ParseCERT {
    private static void usage() {
        System.err.println("Usage : CERT.[RSA|EC|DSA] out.x509.pem");
        System.exit(2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 2) usage();

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
        byte[] data = new byte[fis.available()];
        fis.read(data);
        fis.close();

        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        ArrayList<Certificate> certs = new ArrayList<Certificate>();
        CMSSignedData cms = new CMSSignedData(data);
        Collection<?> collection = cms.getCertificates().getMatches(null);
        for (Object o : collection) {
            if (o instanceof X509CertificateHolder) {
                certs.add(
                    new JcaX509CertificateConverter()
                    .setProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME)
                    .getCertificate((X509CertificateHolder) o)
                );
            }
        }
        if (certs.isEmpty()) throw new RuntimeException("No X509 certs found");

        Certificate cert1 = certs.get(0);
        System.out.println(" Type      : " + cert1.getType());
        PublicKey publicKey = cert1.getPublicKey();
        String algorithm = publicKey.getAlgorithm();
        System.out.println(" Algorithm : " + algorithm);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(args[1]);
        byte[] pembytes = convertToPem(cert1);
        fos.write(pembytes);
        fos.close();
    }

    private static byte[] convertToPem(Certificate cert) throws Exception {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        JcaPEMWriter pw = new JcaPEMWriter(sw);
        pw.writeObject(cert);
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        return sw.toString().getBytes();
    }

    public static byte[] convertToPem2(Certificate cert) throws Exception {
        String cert_begin = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n";
        String end_cert = "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";
        String b64 = Base64.toBase64String(cert.getEncoded()).replaceAll("(.{64})", "$1\n");
        if (b64.charAt(b64.length() - 1) != '\n') end_cert = "\n" + end_cert;
        String outpem = cert_begin + b64 + end_cert;
        return outpem.getBytes();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android, you can read the content of the [digital certificate](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) (*META-INF/CERT.RSA*) of a package using the [X509Certificate](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/security/cert/X509Certificate.html) abstract class.

```
final String appPackage = "com.example"  // TODO: Add here the package name!!

try {
    final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    final ApplicationInfo ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(appPackage, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    if ( ai != null ) {
        final PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageInfo(this.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

        if ( pi != null ) {
            final Signature[] signatures = pi.signatures;

            if ( (pi.signatures != null) && (pi.signatures.length > 0) ) {
                for ( final Signature signature : signatures ) {
                    if ( signature != null ) {
                        final InputStream certInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(signature.toByteArray());
                        final CertificateFactory certFactory;
                        final X509Certificate x509Cert;

                        try {
                            certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");

                            if ( certFactory != null ) {
                                x509Cert = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(certInputStream);

                                if ( x509Cert != null ) {
                                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

                                    Log.d(TAG, "Certificate Owner: " + x509Cert.getSubjectDN().toString());
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Certificate Issuer: " + x509Cert.getIssuerDN().toString());
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Certificate Serial Number: " + x509Cert.getSerialNumber().toString());
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Certificate Algorithm: " + x509Cert.getSigAlgName());
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Certificate Version: " + x509Cert.getVersion());
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Certificate OID: " + x509Cert.getSigAlgOID());
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Certificate Valid From: " + dateFormat.format( x509Cert.getNotBefore() ));
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Certificate Valid To: " + dateFormat.format( x509Cert.getNotAfter() ));

                                    try {
                                        final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
                                        md.update( x509Cert.getEncoded() );

                                        Log.d(TAG, "Certificate SHA-256: " + getHex(md.digest()));
                                    }
                                    catch ( NoSuchAlgorithmException e ) {
                                        //Debug:
                                        Log.e(TAG, "MessageDigest ERROR: " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
                                        //e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch ( final CertificateException e ) {
                            //Debug:
                            Log.e(TAG, "CertificateFactory ERROR: " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
                            //e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch ( final PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e ) {
    //Debug:
    Log.e(TAG, "ApplicationInfo ERROR: " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
    //e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Where the *getHex()* method used to extract the **SHA-256 hash** of the digital certificate is the following:

```
/**
 * Get the hex value of a raw byte array.
 *
 * @param raw  the raw byte array.
 * @return the hex value.
 */
public static String getHex( byte[] raw ) {
    final String HEXES = "0123456789abcdef";

    if ( (raw == null) || (raw.length == 0) ) {
        return null;
    }

    final StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder( 2 * raw.length );
    for ( final byte b : raw ) {
        hex.append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0xF0) >> 4)).append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0x0F)));
    }

    return hex.toString();
}
```

Furthermore, you can extract all the entries of the **owner** and the **issuer** fields (retrieved using the [getSubjectDN()](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/security/cert/X509Certificate.html#getSubjectDN%28%29) an the [getIssuerDN()](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/security/cert/X509Certificate.html#getIssuerDN%28%29) method of the [X509Certificate](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/security/cert/X509Certificate.html) respectively), when they are NOT null, for example, using the following code:

```
for ( final String field : (x509Cert.getSubjectDN().toString()).split(", ") ) {
    if ( field.startsWith("CN=") ) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Common Name: " + field.substring(3));
    }
    if ( field.startsWith("OU=") ) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Organization Unit: " + field.substring(3));
    }
    if ( field.startsWith("O=") ) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Organization name: " + field.substring(2));
    }
    if ( field.startsWith("L=") ) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Locality name: " + field.substring(2));
    }
    if ( field.startsWith("ST=") ) {
        Log.d(TAG, "State or province Name: " + field.substring(3));
    }
    if ( field.startsWith("C=") ) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Country: " + field.substring(2));
    }
    if ( field.startsWith("DC=") ) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Domain Component: " + field.substring(3));
    }
}
```

Comment: You can double-check the values using keytool: "keytool -printcert -file CERT.RSA"